# how to replace duplicate elements with a string in arrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

i want to replace duplicate element with "repeated" string for example,
the arraylist is ["a","b","b","c","a","c","a"], the new array is ["a","b","repeated","c","repeated","repeated","repeated]

i have tried this

```
    ArrayList<String> m = new ArrayList();
    m.add("a");
    m.add("b");
    m.add("b");
    m.add("c");
    m.add("a");
    m.add("c");
    m.add("a");

    System.out.println(m);

    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.size(); j++) {
            if (m.get(i).equals(m.get(j))){
                m.set(j, "repeated");
            }
        }
    }
```

but it's not working

Comment: Please be more specific: what does it do instead of what you want?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: Pretty sure one loop won't do the job.  If you can show otherwise, put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two** errors:

1. You print your list *before* updating. Move the
   `System.println(...)` after the loop.
2. You are replacing *all* elements (not just the duplicates) with the `"repeated"` String since 
   the first comparison in the loop is with the element
   itself.

   ```
   ArrayList<String> m = new ArrayList<>();
   m.add("a");
   m.add("b");
   m.add("b");
   m.add("c");
   m.add("a");
   m.add("c");
   m.add("a");

   for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
       for (int j = i + 1; j < m.size(); j++) {
           if (m.get(i).equals(m.get(j))){
               m.set(j, "repeated");
           }
       }
   }

   System.out.println(m);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

No need to two nested loop. just use a `Set` to store repeated string.

```
Set<String> repeat = new HashSet<>();
int index = -1;
for (String s:m){
   index++;
   m.set(index, repeat.add(s) ? s : "repeated");
}
```

Comment: But that is not what he wants to do.

Comment: @RonnyPolley OP wants to replace duplicate element with _repeated_ string. isn't it?

Comment: sorry I just overlooked the last line. Was a long day. Your're right.